# jQuery update form element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I create a checkbox on a click of a button. I am using https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform which provides an update function to style dynamically create elements which does not work. I got a work around but my problem is that it also reset the already created elements so they double, triple etc.

They are wrapped in a div with a class of `checker`. Is there a way to check if the div is around it first before applying my `$('.table').find('input:checkbox').uniform()`. I have tried different examples but they dont seem to work with my code and my jQuery is still limit.

Thanks

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-160">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id="160" style="opacity: 0;">
        </span>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".fg-button").live("click", function(){
    $('.table').find('input:checkbox').uniform()
    });
```

Comment: Use jQuery 1.7.x and the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for events, the `.live()` function is deprecated

Comment: thanks, was not aware of that

Comment: that works for the first click but any others after that, is there something else I need, I have put in event also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.table input:checkbox').not('div.checker input').uniform()
```

Comment: thanks that works great, it does wipe over the ones that are checked though. If they are checked then the span has a class of checked